# Evernote JS SDK - Can NoteFilter be constructed to filter on notes that do not contain a tagGUID list?

Tags: javascript, node.js, evernote

I've been playing around with the Evernote JS API and am wondering if there's another way to construct the NoteFilter struct to return notes that DO NOT contain a provided list of tagGUIDs. I'm looking through the docs (https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Struct_NoteFilter) but it doesn't look like there's any kind of negation flag or operator that I can pass in. Am I missing something here?

Ultimately, I'm exporting notes out of Evernote and would like to tag them if they've been previously exported. I'd only like to query the notes that don't have this tag applied. Do I have to bring down all notes and then filter on tags? I've got a lot of notes and that seems a little excessive.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, absolutely, using the [search grammar](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/search_grammar.php) (see "Matching Core Note Properties"). The [NoteFilter.words](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Struct_NoteFilter) field is a pass-through for search grammar.

If you really care about tag guids and not names, you can use [listTags](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_listTags) to get the tag names from the guids.